# What is gf_otp_info file?

Tags: security

Is the file gf_otp_info safe or it is a virus? The file is located in the file system. Should I remove it or is it fine?

Comment: Where in the system?

Comment: it is in file manager. The file stands separately,  after all folders in the phone.

Comment: Martina, maybe you could [edit] your post and include a screenshot?

Comment: I can't do a screenshot, but I can see only the name of the file without any extension "gf_otp_info" and the size is 33bytes